# Connect to an Ubuntu VM from a terminal on the host machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, osx

I'm running an instance of Ubuntu Server 14.04 inside VirtualBox, and for multiple reasons, I prefer to work with it using the terminal emulator on the host system (OS X 10.0) than with the default 800x600 terminal from the VM's VGA output.

Currently I have the VM accessing the internet over a bridged adapter so that it appears on the local network. Then, I connect to it over SSH. This setup is of course quite problematic, mainly because I have to actually be connected to a stable local network for this to work, and I have to broadcast the VM to everyone else on the network.

I'm sure there has to be a better way, but I have no idea what it is. Ideally I'd have the VM connecting to the internet through NAT only, and wouldn't need an internet connection to use the setup.

Comment: You could add a second host-only interface to your vm and use this for host-vm-communication.

Comment: @Jodka Could you elaborate on exactly what interface I would use, and what protocol I would use to attach the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to forward a port on localhost to the VM.

I don't know how to do it in VirtualBox, but on Qemu it is a command option:

```
qemu-kvm [all your usual qemu options] -net nic -net user -redir tcp:22122::22
```

Then ssh into it:

```
ssh -p22122 klaatu@localhost
```

I imagine that VirtualBox has a similar function in its GUI settings panel.

Comment: I tried using port forwarding, but after the ssh command I just get `Connection refused`. If I enable SSH on the host the connection isn't refused, it just goes to the host instead of the guest.

Comment: Nevermind. Forwarding to port 22122 worked. Must just have been the port I was forwarding too.

Comment: [Here's how to do it in virtualbox](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10532299/487464)